# Sitecore CLI Scope & AllowedPushOperations property equalents in TDS

Tags: tds, sitecore-cli, scs

We are planning to migrate from TDS to Sitecore CLI and I need to create `module.json` files following the existing TDS setup.

In one of the TDS `.scproj`, I see nodes like this:

```
<SitecoreItem Include="sitecore\content.item"><ItemDeployment>NeverDeploy</ItemDeployment><ChildItemSynchronization>NoChildSynchronization</ChildItemSynchronization></SitecoreItem>
```

There are two properties for each item - `ItemDeployment` and `ChildItemSynchronization`.

I would like to confirm the Sitecore CLI option equivalents for those.

| TDS - ItemDeployment | CLI - allowedPushOperations |
| --- | --- |
| NeverDeploy | ??? |
| DeployOnce | CreateOnly |
| ??? | CreateAndUpdate |
| AlwaysUpdate | CreateUpdateAndDelete |

| TDS - ChildItemSynchronization | CLI - scope |
| --- | --- |
| NoChildSynchronization | SingleItem |
| KeepAllChildrenSynchronized | ItemAndDescendants |
| ??? | ItemAndChildren |
| ??? | DescendantsOnly |

Could you please confirm if what I have mapped is correct.
Also, what should be considered for the missing `???` cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sukesh, I have not used TDS much. So I will be answering SCS part of your question.

*TDS - ItemDeployment > NeverDeploy*

If you want to ignore a specific node in SCS, you can make use of [rules](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/sitecore-content-serialization-configuration-reference.html)

Example, If you wish to **ignore** *`Contact`* Node under *`Home`* -

```
        {
            "name": "Home",
            "path": "/sitecore/content/Home",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "path": "/sitecore/content/Home/Contact",
                    "scope": "ignored"
                }
            ]
        }
```

Hope this helps !